# Ftp folder permission for a custum contact form

Tags: joomla-2.5, form, file-permissions

I built my own custom form which is inside a Contact folder with the 755 permission. Since my email address is inside the contact.php should I change the permission to 700?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, all of your folders should be set to 755 and files should be set to 644.

With Joomla, the only file that should ever need to be different (optional) is your configuration.php file which can be set to 444

Comment: Thanks Lodder! But in this case everyone could find my email address since read + execute are enable?

Comment: 644 means you can change it and others can view it. However it won't be an easy task trying to view it. As it's a PHP file, it doesn't render text or does not open the same way as a HTML file for example. To be honest, I would suggest making your contact form a proper Joomla module. Creating standalone PHP scripts for Joomla is not recommended unless you have a valid reason to be doing so or you know exactly what you're doing

Comment: Would it be more secure in a jumi module ?

Comment: If it were me, I would make it a Joomla module instead.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it helped. I would liked to have given you more info, however chmod permissions are not my strong point. Only know more or less the basics and what Joomla use